# Update Project's attribute value from Different Page

Tags: acumatica

I need help to update the value of Project's attribute from different page.
[image]

I have fetched the attribute value in 'Appointments' page using following code.

```
protected void FSAppointment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        var row = (FSAppointment)e.Row;
        AppointmentEntry graph = (AppointmentEntry)cache.Graph;
        if (graph.ServiceOrderRelated.Current != null)
        {
            int? projectID = graph.ServiceOrderRelated.Current.ProjectID;
            ProjectEntry projectGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
            projectGraph.Project.Current = projectGraph.Project.Search<PMProject.contractID>(projectID);
            foreach (CSAnswers att in projectGraph.Answers.Select())
            {
                if (att.AttributeID == "ESTHOURS")
                {
                    cache.SetValueExt<FieldService.ServiceDispatch.FSAppointmentExt.usrProjectEstimatedRemainingHours>(row, att.Value);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]

And, now I want user to be able to update that particular attribute's value from 'Appointments' page.

For that, I had written following code by overriding the Persist method of 'Appointments' page.

```
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        if (Base.ServiceOrderRelated.Current != null)
        {
            using (PXTransactionScope scope = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                int? projectID = Base.ServiceOrderRelated.Current.ProjectID;
                ProjectEntry projectGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
                var project = projectGraph.Project.Search<PMProject.contractID>(projectID);
                var answers = projectGraph.Answers.Select();
                foreach (CSAnswers att in answers)
                {
                    if (att.AttributeID == "ESTHOURS")
                    {
                        att.Value = "20";
                    }
                }
                projectGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            }

        }
        baseMethod();
    }
```

But still it is not updating the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to realize is that the attribute system is different that the usual DAC->SQL system.  CSAnswers is a unnormalized table of values for all the attributes. They are linked to a DAC document by RefNoteID. See select * from CSAnswers where AttributeID = 'ESTHOURS'  In the code above you are altering every project's 'esthours'.  You're also missing a statement where you tell the graph to update the cache with your altered object.  Something like projectGraph.Answers.Update(att);